# xtensor and xsimd: improve performance on reduction

Tags: python, c++, numpy, simd, xtensor

I'm trying to get the same performance with [xtensor](https://github.com/QuantStack/xtensor) on the reduction operations (e.g. sum of elements) as in NumPy.

I enable [xsimd](https://github.com/QuantStack/xsimd) for parallel computing, but it has no effect.

The following is the benchmark code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "xtensor/xreducer.hpp"
#include "xtensor/xrandom.hpp"
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


pair<double, double> timeit(int size, int n=30){
    double total_clocks = 0;
    double total_sum = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        xt::xtensor<double, 1> a = xt::random::rand({size}, 0., 1.);
        int start = clock();

        double s = xt::sum(a, xt::evaluation_strategy::immediate)();

        int end = clock();
        total_sum += s; total_clocks += end-start;
    }
    return pair<double, double>(total_clocks/CLOCKS_PER_SEC/n, total_sum); 
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i=5;i<8;i++){
        int size = pow(10, i);
        pair<double, double> ret = timeit(size);
        cout<<"size: "<<size<< " \t " <<ret.first<<" sec\t"<<ret.second<<endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

And compile this with and without enabling **xsimd** and all optimisations enabled(-O3):

```
$ g++ -DXTENSOR_USE_XSIMD -O3  -march=native -I/home/--user--/install_path/include "./18. test speed 2.cpp" -o a && ./a
size: 100000     0.0001456 sec     1.49984e+06
size: 1000000    0.0013149 sec     1.50002e+07
size: 10000000   0.0125417 sec     1.49995e+08
```

```
$ g++ -O3  -march=native -I/home/--user--/install_path/include "./18. test speed 2.cpp" -o a && ./a 
size: 100000     0.0001433 sec     1.49984e+06
size: 1000000    0.0012621 sec     1.50002e+07
size: 10000000   0.0124868 sec     1.49995e+08
```

By the way, the same operation using numpy:

```
$ python bench.py
size: 100000     0.000030 sec
size: 1000000    0.000430 sec
size: 10000000   0.005144 sec
```

**About 4 times faster!**

**Setup**

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Core i7 CPU
- Latest versions of packages

How can I improve xtensor performance?
Thanks in advance))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/QuantStack/xtensor/issues/1704) that I have opened
`-mavx2` and `-ffast-math` flags should be enabled!

```
$ g++ -mavx2 -ffast-math -DXTENSOR_USE_XSIMD -O3 -I/home/--user--/install_path/include ./bench.cpp -o a && ./a
size: 100000        3.489e-05 sec   4.99932e+06
size: 1000000       0.00050792 sec  4.99989e+07
size: 10000000      0.00544542 sec  4.99997e+08
```

Thanks to [dengbangjie](https://github.com/dengbangjie)!